# I wanna change my Google drive permission. Root have permission and other user can't access it

Tags: 14.04, google

I'm trying to open my Google drive with local user. It's open but I can't modify any file.

It showing:

```
Could not load image '1045132_188173428016025_21822043_n.jpg'.
Failed to open input stream for file.
```

Comment: How did you set up your Google drive initially?

Answer (score 0):

I believe running the below command will fix your issue.

sudo apt-get install mtp-tools

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mtp-tools